# how to remove brackets and single cots, should have flower braces in list using python

Tags: python-3.x

**I tired this code**

```
>>> do = [{'no': [0], 'name': ['MSI Afterburner 4.6.2'], 'version': ['4.6.2']}, {'no': [1], 'name': ['AnyDesk'], 'version': ['ad 5.4.2']}]
>>> do1 = ", ".join([f"{k}: {v[0]}" for k, v in do[0].items()])
>>> print (do1)
no: 0, name: MSI Afterburner 4.6.2, version: 4.6.2
```

**needed output**

```
{no: 0, name: MSI Afterburner 4.6.2, version: 4.6.2},{no:1, name: AnyDesk, version: ad 5.4.2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need `str.replace`

**Ex:**

```
do = [{'no': [0], 'name': ['MSI Afterburner 4.6.2'], 'version': ['4.6.2']}, {'no': [1], 'name': ['AnyDesk'], 'version': ['ad 5.4.2']}]
print(str(do).replace("'", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", ""))
```

**Output:**

```
{no: 0, name: MSI Afterburner 4.6.2, version: 4.6.2}, {no: 1, name: AnyDesk, version: ad 5.4.2}
```